# How to get instance to Dispatcher to stop a thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

To escape thread affinity, I have used below code to update the UI control

```
public void Start()
{
 while (true)
 {
 App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate 
 {
    Messenger.Default.Send(DateTime.Now + "  sent", "SimulatorLogs");
 });
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
 }
}
```

Now, I wish to stop this `while` loop based on user action. May be by clicking "stop" button in a GUI.

So, How can I access this thread to stop the loop?

```
 public void Stop()
 {
       App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => App.Current.Shutdown()));
        //This is shutting down entire application :(
 }
```

Comment: If your while-loop  _only_ invokes then use a Timer instead.

Comment: when i use timer, i get "This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread". so i used Dispatcher.  can u help with some code samples?

Comment: .NET has many timers, use a DispatcherTimer. That always runs on the right thread.

Comment: YES, IT WORKED!